# aggregate check before modifying data and locking

Tags: postgresql, locking, aggregate

Imagine the following scenario, we have a  table, where rows inserts with some constraints. 
For example,

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ....
2. Check,if count less than some value
3. If condition is true - INSERT ..., otherwise - ROLLBACK

It's working,if we don't have many concurrent queries. 
For handle concurrent requests, there are several ways:

1. Save counter into another table, or Redis. And manage this counter on every update.
2. Lock the whole table before each insert.

I'm using PostgreSQL.What are the best way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `statement_timeout` and `lock_timeout` explicitly `set` by each user session instead. Look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html) for details.

Comment: How is that connected to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Locking the table is pretty extreme and will hurt concurrency badly.

Maintaining a counter in a separate table would be better; it would essentially serialize `INSERT`s (the next transaction can only update the counter once the previous transaction has released the lock with a `COMMIT`).

A third way is to use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions. If all transactions involved are `SERIALIZABLE`, your condition will automatically be guaranteed as long as you perform the `SELECT count(*) ...` and the `INSERT` in a single transaction.
The downside is that transactions can be aborted with serialization errors, and you have to be ready to retry them.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.